# Why expectation of sample median of negative x = negative expectation of sample median x?

Tags: statistics, real-numbers

M means sample median below. Note M is "symmetric". Then $EM(-X_1, -X_2,...,-X_n) =-EM(X_1, X_2,...,X_n)$

Why the above is always true?

Comment: Median (roughly middle value of sorted data) is transformed to "mirror image" in multiplying by $-1:$ Median of $(1,2,3,4,5)$ is $3;$ median of $(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1)$ is $-3.$ // Don't understand how this is puzzling. Maybe try a few simple examples, so you can see that the claim is true.

Comment: but what if our data contains both positive values and negative values? Then I feel puzzled.